# NSUserDefaults not saving integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, macos, nsuserdefaults

I'm having some problems saving to an existing key

```
//This was previously set and contains this value 1436544831921
NSInteger timestamp = [[NSUserDefualts standardUserDefualts] integerForKey:aKey];

NSInteger newValue = [self doSomethingWithOldValue:timestamp] //returns 1436631948002

[[NSUserDefualts standardUserDefualts] setInteger:newValue forKey:aKey];
[[NSUserDefualts standardUserDefualts] synchronize];
```

Is something wrong with this implementation? It is not saving but persisting the previously saved value.

Comment: You realize that this value is larger than a 32 bit integer can hold - it would take a 64 bit integer to hold it. Try setting, then reading, then setting, then reading a value like "100".

Comment: @DavidH I tried doing that, but it's not even setting it to "100", it keeps the old value.

Comment: Try find may be somewhere in your code you also changing that key. At app launch for example/

Comment: @Cy-4AH Thank you, the key is a constant. And this is the only place the value is being set. After the second time it comes to this point it does not save any value at all under this key again.

Comment: @CRD added to watch list

Comment: use object, `NSNumber` instead..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting your `NSUserDefaults` first like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *userPrefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

You can also try to use a NSString like this:

```
NSInteger newValue = [self doSomethingWithOldValue:timestamp];
NSString* newValueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", newValue];

[userPrefs setObject:newValueString forKey:aKey];
```

Also make sure that your `aKey` is set correctly

Comment: I don't know what was the problem but using strings instead definitely solved the issue, I tried everything, integers, values, nsnumber as object and this is the only one that actually worked. Thanks!

Comment: @trick14 I'm not really sure about that but I read in the class reference that `setInteger:forKey:` invokes `setObject:forKey:` as part of its implementation. This made me try using `setObject:forKey:`.

Comment: @TomWayne but do you have any clue if and why NSUserdefaults won't parse integers?Im having the same problem saving an instance that has integer properties that come back as nil (or 0). I will use the string-quickfix, but its nasty and I don't like not knowing why:P